# Convert MAC address to integer in Vertica

Tags: sql, database, hex, vertica

I want to covert MAC address to integer format in Vertica database. They are in the form like below -

```
1e:07:02:15:3a:88
1e:07:02:1b:64:ab
...
```

I used the following query to convert them to integer -

```
SELECT hex_to_integer(MAC) FROM Network_table;
```

where MAC is the column name containing MAC addresses and Network_table is the table name.

It is showing me the following error -

> Invalid input syntax for numeric: "0x1e:07:02:15:3a:88"

I think its because the address contains ":" symbols. Any idea how can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regexp_replace()` for vertica.

```
SELECT hex_to_int(regexp_replace('1e:07:02:15:3a:88',':'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try `translate` function, along with `hex_to_integer`.

E.g.:

```
dbadmin=> select hex_to_integer(translate('1e:07:02:15:3a:88',':',''));

 hex_to_integer
----------------
 33015448550024
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need,
`CONV('C404158996CD', 16,10)` ("convert 'C404158996CD' from base 16 to base 10")

here 'C404158996CD' is a mac address.

Or you can try this

```
select
concat (left (b.mh, 2),':',mid(b.mh,3,2),':',mid(b.mh,5,2),':',mid(b.mh,7,2),':',mid(b.mh,9,2),':',mid(b.mh,11,2))

from (
    select lpad (hex (a.mac_as_int), 12, '0') as mh
    from (
        select 1234567890 as mac_as_int
    ) a
) b
```